# How to get feature id by using QgsExpression?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I want to get feature id of the attributes by using QgsExpression. I use this code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() 
expr = QgsExpression('$id')
it = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))
values = [i.id() for i in it]
```

However, in my layer, there are 20 points. It gives me 19 points. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Why would you use QgsExpression, when it is easier to use the QgsFeature class to get the ID from the feature itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple change:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() 
expr = QgsExpression('$id + 1')
it = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))
values = [i.id() for i in it]
```

Comment: And this solve the issue?

Comment: Yes very interesting